# How to return error if a file does not contain specific data types

Tags: c, scanf

I am reading a text file which contains the following in the particular order: capital-letter number capital-letter (eg. C4S). I can sucessfully do this using sscanf, where 'line' is the char array found from fgets.

Pseudo code:

```
sscanf(line, "%c %d %c", &firstLetter, &number, &secondLetter)
```

I want to return an error if the file does not contain 'capital-letter number capital-letter' in that order. How could I do this?

Comment: Just test `firstLetter` and the other variables with functions such as `isdigit()` and `isalpha()`. But first of all check `scanf` return value.

Comment: Your quoted format and your code do not agree. Are there spaces in the file or not? It would vastly help to show a formatted example of input, with lines that should and should not trip the requested error.

Comment: The input would be C4 S, and if I were to printf("%c %d %c, firstLetter, number, secondLetter); the output would be C 4 S.

Comment: In regards to Roberto's comment, yes that is a good idea but can't you only get the variable (eg firstLetter) from already defining what type it is in the sscanf? In this case we could have three letters which would then cause the sscanf to play up since it expects the digit in the second entry.

Comment: No C4ST wouldnt work, needs to be the three values passed from the file as it is used further in a  program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against using `sscanf` in basically every situation where you are not already absolutely sure that the provided input will match your format string. So what you can do instead here is first perform such a check and only then, if it succeeds, call `sscanf`:

```
if (strlen(line) == 3 && isupper(line[0]) && isdigit(line[1]) && isupper(line[2])) {
   sscanf(line, "%c%1d%c", &c1, &d, &c2);
} else {
   puts("line not valid");
   // error handling goes here
}
```

I changed some variable names and the format string slightly but you can easily adapt this.

Comment: Would this work if the three variables had space between them? The file will be flexible so it could be: C4S, C  4S, C4  S etc etc

Comment: No, In that case I would first strip all spaces from "line". There are several other StackOverflow answers that explain how.